# Extracting JS objects from PDF files using pdfcpu library

Tags: go, pdf, pdfcpu

I'm trying to extract JS from PDF files as a requirement of safe upload. Using pdfcpu I can extract pdf's objects by index, but one of the problems is that we're receiving bytes, is there a way to work with that instead of having to write it into a file on disk?

Also, does pdfcpu provides a way for extracting JS in a more declarative manner, instead of having to loop over each object?

Comment: pdfcpu doesn't have a high-level interface for interacting with objects by kind, like iText does (I saw your previous post). But, Horst (the author of pdfcpu) is fairly responsive to issues, so if you were to open a new issue and ask how to get the JavaScript out, I'd expect them to respond favorably. I'd like to see the answer myself... I tried reading into the model/api, but couldn't make enough sense out of it to get the JS dict. And to answer your specific question directly, all PDF apis internally will be looping over objects and filtering... that's just how PDF itself is architected.

Answer (score 0):

Currently pdfcpu does not have such an option.

The simplest means to detect JS in pdf is using pdfinfo (poppler not xpdf)

`pdfinfo -js`                  : print all JavaScript in the PDF

HOWEVER there are many legitimate reasons for JavaScript entries such as fields and dates and even many hyperlinks.

```
poppler\22.02>pdfinfo -js 5T2lz
I/O Error: Couldn't open file '5T2lz': No error.

poppler\22.02>pdfinfo -js ACFrOgAYzyVpaYkP3s966uMLaUX_Hom772FkCVBh0ISIVWlRKHPfuao1GbVDBiwPxr90Gw-xMFeSv1SJLp_yKPFVHFv57n2HtyPuweOe0BWwe_me5CR7bwOku8Mi2QvOfw0hpoIUt0XRc62R4Hxp.pdf
Syntax Warning: Illegal URI-type link
Syntax Warning: Illegal URI-type link
Syntax Warning: Illegal URI-type link
Syntax Warning: Illegal URI-type link
Syntax Warning: Illegal URI-type link

poppler\22.02>pdfinfo -js odd.pdf
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error (30): Illegal character ')'
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table

poppler\22.02>pdfinfo -js runme.pdf
Name Dictionary "AScript":
app.alert({
cMsg: "Gotcha! Try again!",
cTitle: "Acme Testing Service"
});

poppler\22.02>pdfinfo -js "..\..\imm1294ea Copy.pdf"
Name Dictionary "!ADBE::0100_VersChkStrings":
if (typeof(this.ADBE) == "undefined")
   this.ADBE = new Object();
ADBE.LANGUAGE = "ENU";
ADBE.Viewer_string_Title = "Adobe Acrobat";
ADBE.Viewer_string_Update_Desc = "Adobe Interactive Forms Update";
ADBE.Viewer_string_Update_Reader_Desc = "Adobe Reader 7.0.5";
ADBE.Reader_string_Need_New_Version_Msg = "This PDF file requires a newer version of Adobe Reader. Press OK to download the latest version or see your system administrator.";
ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Reader_601 = "This PDF form requires a newer version of Adobe Reader.....blah blah blah

poppler\22.02>pdfinfo -js "..\..\"???"???(????).pdf"
I/O Error: Couldn't open file '..\.."??????(????).pdf': No error.

poppler\22.02>pdfinfo -js "..\..\xss Copy.pdf"
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

There are many reasons detection can fail, one is a password encrypted file will not always be easily readable and two most dangerous scripts will be intentionally obscured from simple detection.
[image]
The "safe" way to run a first level analysis for AS, ES or JS exploits is use a dedicated sandbox server with automated PDF file opener, that looks for untoward code behaviours. And for that you can use an account on VirusTotal or similar service.